# Django channels

Tags: django, django-channels

Я пытаюсь использовать библиотеку каналов Django для моего проекта. По сути, я пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм: пользователь «X» нажимает кнопку, чтобы начать новый чат с пользователем «Y». Саму запись в базу данных об этом событии я сделал, но как я могу включить обоих этих пользователей в группу, чтобы они могли общаться друг с другом в режиме реального времени? Не могу решить эту проблему долгое время

Comment: На **ru**.stackoverflow.com вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Я пытаюсь использовать библиотеку каналов Django для моего проекта. По сути, я пытаюсь реализовать следующий алгоритм: пользователь «X» нажимает кнопку, чтобы начать новый чат с пользователем «Y». Саму запись в базу данных об этом событии я сделал, но как я могу включить обоих этих пользователей в группу, чтобы они могли общаться друг с другом в режиме реального времени? Не могу решить эту проблему долгое время (((Спасибо!

Comment: раньше оба пользователя добавлялись в одну группу, а потом эта группа методом send, вроде, рассылала всем сообщения. Как сейчас сделано не знаю.

Comment: в чём польза Вашего ответа? Или ответ ради ответа?